# Printing issue (Canon LBP2900)

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

When I print to my Canon LBP2900, Ubuntu shows printing completes, but nothing is really printed.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? How did you set up the printer and its driver originally? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I've seen this happen before. Is there paper in the printer?

Comment: so this device needs Canon's CAPT driver; latest version is 2.71 from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html

Comment: they are all asking you: how did you set the printer up, to print: which drivers did  you install etc

Comment: so Navneet: this printer needs the Canon CAPT driver; we can guide you through; have you installed the CAPT drivers please; happy to guide on that too

Answer (score 1):

4 steps are needed:

**1) install the drivers**

**2) Register the printer (PPD)**

**3) Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file**

**4) Start ccpd daemon**

**STEP ONE**
go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html and download and save what will be *linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz*

open a terminal; copy each command below; line by line; paste it into the terminal; hit ENTER key after each paste;

```
cd Downloads
tar -zxvf linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz
cd linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian
sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb
```

*Now we assume you have only one usb printer; and that is the LBP2900*;

**STEP TWO**

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -P /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
```

**STEP THREE**

```
sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
```

**STEP FOUR**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

then you should be able to open LibreOffice or some programme and see if you can print